# AjaxControlToolkit ValidatorCalloutExtender does not work with UnobtrusiveValidation

Tags: validation, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a WebForms application. If I target the application to use .NET 4.6 framework using `<httpruntime targetFramework="4.6"/>`, the ValidatorCalloutExtender does not work. If I switch off the UnobtrusiveValidation using `<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>`, the validation works fine. We don't want to turn off the UnobtrusiveValidation setting. Is there any other solution?

Thank you.